Plotting two functions in 3D
To make my problem clear, suppose i want to plot x+y=50 and x+y=100 on the same 3D plot. I have tried the following but haven't gotten the correct result:
Plot3D[y + x = 50, y + x = 100, {x, 0, 200, y, 0, 200}]

Plot3D [{y + x = 100}, {y + x + 50}, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]

Plot3D[y + x = 50, y + x = 100, {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 200}]

and various other permutations. Is there some syntax that will make this work? or is it necessary to use another function besides Plot3D?
Thanks for any insights.
Kerry

You're missing brackets, as is clear from the documentation.

Some good examples in the documentation, always worth having a look. See the 3rd example.
Plot3D[{x + y == 100, x + y == 50}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]


